# Drag and drop is not working properly with jigsaw puzzle

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

I am working on a jigsaw puzzle for children age 4.

The puzzle contains 16 pieces called p1 to p16.

The problem is when i drag and drop for example piece p1, p2 and p15 and p16 in to place and then start dragging a piece with a lower number for instance p4 then piece p4 is visible only on top of p1 and p2 but not visible on top of p15 and p16. I do understand that is because of the stacking order, but i am wondering if it can be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest solution is to just call the addChild() method, whenever you start to drag any of your instances.

something like here:

```
function yourMouseDownHandlerFunction(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
    addChild(e.currentTarget);
}
```